# How would I print a certain part of a list on the same line, and another part of lists on different lines in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
```

how would I get this to print something like this:

```
1 2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

code

```
l=[10,20,30,40,50,60]
n=3
for i in range(len(l)):
    if i==0:print(' '.join([str(elem) for elem in l[:n]]))
    if i>(n-1): print(l[i])
```

n is the position in the list you want to end the firt line

```
10 20 30
40
50
60
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `end=` parameter of the print function to stay on same line, and a normal print to create a new line according to your requirements:

```
L = [1,2,3,4]
for n in L:
    print(n, end=' ')  # will stay on same line after printing
    if n>=2: print()   # will go to a new line for items after 2
```

output:

```
1 2 
3 
4
```